# How would I write a function to search through a text file,return those details then delete them from the file?

Tags: python-3.x

[This is the text file containing the details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VgVFs.png)I've been tasked to create a function that updates the detail files based on the entered name.So the function is supposed to receive the keyword and compare it to the details and extract the details that are of that specific name then put the details in a separate file.This is what I've come up with so far but it doesn't work as intended,so if anyone could help with a better solution it would be highly appreciated.

my code:

```
checkedOut = open('checked_out.txt','w+')
Details = open('Details.txt','r+')

l = []
dum = []
l2 = []
for i in Details:
    x = i.split()
    l.append(x)

count = 0
for t in l:
    for p in t:
        print(p)
        if p != key:
            print("Not in records")
        elif p == key:
            dum = l[count:count+9]
            print(dum)
    count+=1
```

Comment: Can you give us some of your current output, your expected output and the example files you are using.

Comment: I'm really just looking for a better solution

Comment: You haven't attempted to use your output file `checkedOut`. Instead of `for p in t:` try `if key in t:` and then `t.index(...)` etc.

Comment: @SamsGottheblues we still need to know how the files are formatted, are the files storing key value pairs on each line, where each detail corresponds to a key only, or are the files storing lines that will match the details exactly?

Comment: I have attached a screenshot of the file

Comment: You will still have to elaborate, if the screenshot is of the input file, what should the output file look like. Break the problem down into steps, are you just matching the name? are you extracting all the details for each match?

Comment: The output file needs to be formatted exactly like the input and we are only using the name to search and match. The user is first asked to enter the name and this name is used as the argument for the function which then removes the details that are specific to that name FROM the orginal file containing all the details then added to a new file containing all the checked out users

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do the trick. First read the whole of the `Details` file in and split it up into a list of lines using the `readlines()` function.

You can then loop over the lines, incrementing the counter by `10` each time as the details are 10 lines long (You could also alter the `line_num` count based on the `======` separators). If the `line_num` count is pointing to a line that is equal to `Name: inputted_name` we can write the lines to the `checkedOut` file and delete them from the list of details lines, otherwise increment `line_num` by `10` and loop again. *NB: the checked out file is opened in `append` mode.*

Once you've readched the end of the file, close the `checkedOut` file and overwrite the `Details` file with the new lines that have the copied data removed.

```
name = "sam" # or use input("Please give a name: ")
checkedOutFileName = 'checked_out.txt'
detailsFileName = 'Details.txt'

# Open checked out file in append mode
checkedOut = open(checkedOutFileName,'a')
# Open details file in read mode
Details = open(detailsFileName,'r')

# Read all lines of Details as a list of lines
DetailsLines = Details.readlines()

# Close the Details file
Details.close()

line_num = 0
end_line = len(DetailsLines)

while line_num < end_line:
    line = DetailsLines[line_num]
    # Check if line is equal to "Name: " + the given name
    if line.strip() == f"Name: {name}":
        # write matching details to checkedOut file
        checkedOut.writelines(DetailsLines[line_num:line_num+10])
        print(*DetailsLines[line_num:line_num+10])
        # Remove details from details lines
        del DetailsLines[line_num:line_num+10]
        # Reduce end_line by 10 lines
        end_line -= 10
        # Continue without incrementing line count, as we've just removed the lines
        continue
    line_num += 10

checkedOut.close()

# Overwrite Details file with modified data
Details = open(detailsFileName,'w')
Details.writelines(DetailsLines)
# Add a new line at the end
Details.write("")
Details.close()
```